# MVC response view not displayed by browser

Tags: model-view-controller, browser, freeze, no-response

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that works fine most of the time. Occasionally, users complain that they submit an action request and the application appears to hang (i.e. no response is received by the browser even after several minutes and eventually the browser times out.)  I can see from HttpWatch that the request is being submitted, IIS logs show the server receiving the request and the application logs show the request action being invoked and completing normally.  HttpWatch gives an error which is usually 'ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_RESET' or 'NS_ERROR_NET_RESET'.

The application also does a number of Ajax requests to the same server which all appear to function normally - the 'hang' situation only occurs on full HTTP page loads (i.e. not Ajax requests.)

At first I thought this was browser related, but it happens both with IE8 and IE9 and with FireFox 17, which may be the reason for the two different error messages posted above.c

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?